# How frequent people tweet about a topic?

Tags: java, datetime, twitter4j

In my program I am getting tweets from twitter for a specific query. I want to calculate how frequent people tweet about this topic. Up to now what I did is;

1. I got the dates of two tweets and found the difference
2. sum up those differences and divided it to number of tweets.

However, there is a problem which is the number of tweets can be odd so every time I can't get two tweets and this situation may give me wrong answer.

So what can I do for this problem? Or is there a better way to find how frequent people tweet?

I am using twitter4j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you've got a complicated way of finding the mean average ;)

Your algorithm can be simplified to "Take the date difference between the first and last tweets, and divide by the number of tweets".

Comment: oh, thank you very much RB :) if I got at least 15 reputations, I would vote up your answer. So sorry about that. Anyways I am accepting this :)